# ListDefinition Error 'ctx' is undefined

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have create a DocumentLibrary list using the SharePoint UI and export it using the SharePoint Solution Generator 2008 (VSeWSS 1.3) to a Visual Studio .NET project.

Then I have made a webpart to show items from the document library using the ListViewByQuery with som input parameters. I have put the ListViewByQuery into a Ajax UpdatePanel. The list item menu rase an error 'ctx' is undefined. ctx is defined in the schema.xml file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work-around;

Had the same problem with a document library - to work-around I dragged the standard control part onto the page and made it non-visible (the doclibrary plugin )
Make sure that in this hidden control's view the "Name (linked to document with edit menu)" field is in the view.

That field will cause the creation of a ctx to support the edit drop-down.